# how to add custom variable to ensure in puppet manifest?

Tags: ruby, puppet, manifest

I was wondering if i can add custom values to ensure in manifest file of puppet module.
Valid values are Valid values are absent (also called false), file, present, directory, link. Values can match /./.

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/types/file.html#file-attribute-ensure

```
file { '/etc/inetd.conf':
  ensure => 'fetch',
}
```

so here i would like to add user defined value, can we do that ?
if yes then how can i do that ?

Comment: You can't do that, although you could define your own custom file type in Ruby.  https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/puppet-types-and/9781449339319/ch04.html  I suspect there's a better way to solve whatever problem you're trying to solve without going down that path.

Comment: Custom type is the first thing that comes to mind, although I recommend http://garylarizza.com/blog/2013/11/25/fun-with-providers/ as a tutorial instead. You may also be able to achieve what you want with a defined resource type wrapped around `file` https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_defined_types.html.

Comment: Also is it possible to use puppet modules for monitoring and hit a GET operations on APIs ?
I can do POST/PUT/DELETE by using present/absent in the "enure" field, but is there any way to perform the GET operation as well.